# Converting Grammar to CNF

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

So I have to convert the following grammar to CNF. However in order for me to do so, I know I will have to first:

```
   i)   eliminate the recursive start symbol
   ii)  eliminate null-rules to construct an essentially non-contracting
        grammar
   iii) eliminate unit rules
```

`S -> SS
S -> aSb
S -> 1`

But I am so lost and this is my first time working with coversions to CNF. I know the basic principals on converting the grammar, but whats getting me confused is the above transformations that I have to do first. Can someone please show me how i would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:

(i) Eliminate the recursive start symbol. This is very easy: just introduce a new symbol $S'$, replace $S$ by $S'$ in the rules, and add the rule $S\to S'$. This give the following grammar:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&S  &\to S' \\
&S' &\to S'S' \\
&S' &\to aS'b \\
&S' &\to 1
\end{split}\end{equation}$$

(ii) The grammar has no null rules (*aka* "empty productions").

(ii.5) Ensure that every rule has at most one terminal symbol. Do this by introducing a nonterminal $U_x$ for each terminal $x$, and adding a rule $U_x\to x$. For each occurrence of $x$ in a rule whose RHS has length at least $2$, replace $x$ with $U_x$. Transforming the given grammar in that way gives:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&S  &\to S' \\
&S' &\to S'S' \\
&S' &\to U_aS'U_b \\
&U_a&\to a \\
&U_b&\to b \\
&S' &\to 1 \\
\end{split}\end{equation}$$

(iii) Now, the only unit rule is $S\to S'$, but that can't be eliminated.